# Why does my glass look black (not transparent) in the rendering mode?

Tags: materials, glass

[image]Hi everyone, I have a question: Why does my glass look black  (not transparent) in the rendering mode? I have these problem since yesterday, before that I did other projects, the glass stays as a glass... I also put this cup in the other project, which "glass" works, and the cup turns out to be transparent! So I think some settings in the software are different since yesterday, but I can not figure out what...
Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Your _Roughness_ is much too high. For anything else there is not information in your question. (Render Engine? If _Eevee_, what are the other settings like _Blend Mode_, _Shadow Mode_ etc.?)

Comment: ... trying it with my own cup this looks a lot like _Eevee_ with the material set to _Blend Mode_ > _Opaque_ and _Shadow Mode_ > _Opaque_.